# How to merge two GZIP files, while removing the first row from the second file?

Tags: bash, csv, merge, gzip, cat

I have two `gzip` CSV files, each of them has these decompressed contents:

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
```

How do I merge them using a bash function in a way that removes the first row from the second file, so that I get this output? Preferrably I can do it without decompressing either input file.

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
b,2
c,3
```

I already know how to do it with non-gzip files:

```
function merge_files { 
   cat "$1" <(tail +2 "$2") > "$3"; 
}
```

Comment: You can't; the header is what gives the rest of the file meaning. Or, in other words, the compression schema for each file is different, and encoded in the header. In a (weak-ish) analogy, it is like trying to paste together a French file and a Chinese file, and expecting a legible Swahili to come out. Decompress and recompress is not optional: `gzcat file1.gz file2.gz | gzip > file.out`

Comment: I must have misused the word "header". I meant the first row of the decompressed data (in this case, `a,1`).

Comment: Ah lol, my bad. You didn't misuse it, it's just ambiguous. :) But the point still stands, decompression is not optional.

Answer (score 4):

With a minimal change to your code:

```
function merge_files { 
   cat <(gzcat "$1") <(gzcat "$2" | tail +2) | gzip > "$3"; 
}
```

or

```
function merge_files { 
   (
      gzcat "$1";
      gzcat "$2" | tail +2
   ) | gzip > "$3"; 
}
```